# Cheap smartphone for testing a camera-based webapp

Tags: smartphones

I am experimenting on a web app that recreates the idea in [this xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/941). I am doing it using a node.js server hosted on my desktop, connected (via websocket) to two clients running on a web browser. The two clients continually sending camera capture to the server, that combines them and produce a cyan-red 3D anaglyph image.

So I want two phones meeting these requirements:

- Cheap. Really cheap. Cheapest possible.
- Must run at least Android 4 or Firefox OS
- Must have Wi-Fi (may or may not have 2G/3G/4G)
- Should have at least a HD720 (1280 x 720) camera, no need for a rear cam.

I guess that's a pretty large frame, the main requirement is still **cheapest possible**.